# Why the execution plan of same query are different

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Actually i have been assigned a task wherein i have to remove dynamic query and loops(if possible) from an SP. For this purpose i have created a copy of the original SP and working on the new copied SP. I have made certain changes in the new SP and trying to compare the performance of both (old and new) SP using actual execution plan and for that i am executing both the SP with identical parameters.

The problem is that in our database all the SPs we have accepts one parameter in common i.e. session_code (varchar type) and in all SPs we call an another SP at the first place to validate the session_code parameter supplied from the calling application. In my new SP i have not altered the call for the session validation SP and made changes in other dynamic queries. But when i am comparing the actual execution plan of both (old and new) SP, i can see that the cost are different for execution of session validation SP. For my newly created SP it shows cost more than old SP.

Could you guys please help me understand this behavior of optimizer where i have not altered anything in the SP/query.

Comment: Two words - parameter sniffing

Comment: This is what @Raj means by parameter sniffing: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx   Normally it would imply the inverse problem. Your original plan would stick around even as it is stale as compared to the inputs. But you indicated that there are dynamic queries in the SPs. That would cause the SPs to be re-compiled each time.

Comment: Thanks friend for your suggestions. @model_dialog actually i am also using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE every time to clear procedure cache, so that all the time we get new plan to notice performance closely.

Comment: How is `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` going to help you at evaluating real-world performance? Either you're using `with (recompile)` and it does nothing, or you're not and you're getting skewed results.

Comment: @Luaan, i am using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE just to empty the procedure cache. Yes, i am getting different execution after each run. Actually my both SPs (Old and New) calls other SP as well and using DBCC i am trying to prevent optimizer to cache any query while testing the performance only. Kindly suggest if this is not the best way to test performance and should follow other approach.